# Promise returned by NodeJS Async function is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I call sendText, the promise returned by callSendAPI returns as undefined, logged on the console like so:

> Promise return from callSendAPI undefined

I have read up on promises and checked a lot of stack overflow questions, but I haven't been able to grasp which part of my code is wrong. The message sends fine, but the undefined return has the effect of causing await in higher functions to not work correctly.

What am I doing incorrectly in constructing my promise which is causing it to return as undefined?

```
var request = require('request-promise-native');

module.exports = {
  callSendAPI : function (sender_psid,response) {
    return new Promise(async function(resolve,reject) {
      // Construct the message body
      let request_body = {
        "recipient": {
          "id": sender_psid
        },
        "message": response
      }
      // Send the HTTP request to the Messenger Platform
      try {
        var a  = await request({
          "uri": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages",
          "qs": { "access_token": PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
          "method": "POST",
          "json": request_body
        })
      } catch(e) {
        console.error("Unable to send message:" + e);
        return reject(e);
      }
      console.log('message sent!')
      resolve();
    });
  },
  sendText : function(sender_psid,text) {
    return new Promise(async function(resolve,reject) {
      var response = { "text": `${text}` };
      try {
        var a = await module.exports.callSendAPI(sender_psid,response);
        console.log("Promise return from callSendAPI " + a);
      } catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
        return reject();
      }
      console.log("message sent--------------------");
      resolve();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't pass anything to `resolve()`.

Comment: `return new Promise(async function(resolve,reject) {`is invalid. Promise callback should not be async. `request` must be defined as async.

Comment: There's NO reason to wrap a promise around an existing async operation that returns a promise.  That's a promise anti-pattern.  Just return the promise you already have.  And, it's really bizzaare for you to do `a = await fn()` and then never use `a`.  Makes no sense at all.

Comment: @marekful it's not incorrect, it's just a redundant anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your comments everyone. I'm a beginner with node js, so this has been very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a re-write that simplifies your implementation and correctly resolves the promise with a value:

```
var request = require('request-promise-native');

module.exports = {
  async callSendAPI (sender_psid, response) {
    // Construct the message body
    let request_body = {
      recipient: {
        id: sender_psid
      },
      message: response
    };
    // Send the HTTP request to the Messenger Platform
    try {
      var a = await request({
        uri: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages",
        qs: { access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
        method: "POST",
        json: request_body
      });
      console.log('message sent!');
      return a;
    } catch(e) {
      console.error("Unable to send message:" + e);
      throw e;
    }
  },
  async sendText (sender_psid, text) {
    var response = { text: String(text) };
    try {
      var a = await module.exports.callSendAPI(sender_psid,response);
      console.log("Promise return from callSendAPI " + a);
      console.log("message sent--------------------");
      return a;
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
      throw e;
    }
  }
};
```

As suggested by @jfriend00 you can simply return the promise generated by `request()` rather than wrapping it in a try-catch, optionally logging each scenario by chaining a `.then()` like this:

```
var request = require('request-promise-native');

module.exports = {
  async callSendAPI (sender_psid, response) {
    // Construct the message body
    let request_body = {
      recipient: {
        id: sender_psid
      },
      message: response
    };

    // Send the HTTP request to the Messenger Platform
    return request({
      uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
      qs: { access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
      method: 'POST',
      json: request_body
    }).then(value => {
      console.log('message sent!');

      return value;
    }, error => {
      console.error('Unable to send message:', error);

      throw error;
    });
  },
  async sendText (sender_psid, text) {
    var response = { text: String(text) };

    return module.exports.callSendAPI(sender_psid, response).then(value => {
      console.log('Promise return from callSendAPI', value);
      console.log('message sent--------------------');

      return value;
    }, error => {
      console.error(error);

      throw error;
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: You can log it in a `.then()` if you want, but I see your point.

Comment: ...I don't want to? There's nothing wrong with this approach.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it makes sense now.